# Using .NET library in Windows Phone 8.1 application

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, windows-phone-8.1, mscorlib

I want to create Windows Phone 8.1 application in C#. I have a commercial .NET library I need to use which, according to the documentation, is compatible with Windows and Windows Mobile operating systems. When I add a reference to this library in my project and compile, I receive the following error: `Cannot find type System.Collections.CollectionBase in module mscorlib.dll`.

Is there any way to use this library in Windows Phone 8.1 application?

Comment: Check which version you are using Windows phone 8.1(RT) or windows phone 8.1 (Silverlight) also check the documentation for which version of windows phone it is supported

Comment: Documentation does not specify that Windows Phone is supported at all.

Comment: I assume you use RT, so try creating a Silverlight project and include the lib into that project. If it works, the hint 'Windows Phone' seems only to include the Silverlight part...